# Unable to edit selected value from AsyncSelect

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using `AsyncSelect` from `react-select` to populate a list of options asynchronously.

I want that so when you select an option and click the input, you can continue to edit the selection.

Currently, clicking on the input doesn't allow you to edit the current selection, instead allows you to make a brand new search.

I've looked at the `react-select` github for issues and came across

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1868
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1558

However, these fixes do not work for `AsyncSelect`.

```
handleFocus = element => {
  if (this.state.value) {
    // This works for regular Select but not Async
    this.select.state.inputValue = this.state.value.label;
  }
};
render() {
  const { isLoading, options, value } = this.state;

  return (
    <Async
      ref={ref => {
        this.select = ref;
      }}
      isClearable
      blurInputOnSelect={true}
      isDisabled={isLoading}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onCreateOption={this.handleCreate}
      onMenuClose={this.handleMenuClose}
      onFocus={this.handleFocus}
      loadOptions={this.getOptions}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-select-with-fake-service-v9ki2) with the fix that works on `Select` but not on `Aysnc`

Does anyone have any suggestions? It would be greatly appreciated.